# Searching multiple columns for multiple values showing records that match all values only MySQL

Tags: mysql, operators

I am having an issue on how to structure a statement so it will return the records that match multiple values within multiple columns even though the value may not be located in other columns...yeah I know it sounds confusing let me explain.

Let's say I am looking for 2 values ("this" and "that"). Let's also say that I am looking in 4 different columns for these values. Here are 2 scenario statements I have come up with but neither work correctly and I will explain each one.

**Using the AND operator**

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (column1 LIKE '%this%'
    AND column2 LIKE '%this%'
    AND column3 LIKE '%this%'
    AND column4 LIKE '%this%'
    AND column1 LIKE '%that%'
    AND column2 LIKE '%that%'
    AND column3 LIKE '%that%'
    AND column4 LIKE '%that%')
```

If I use the **AND** operator for my statement then each value has to be within each column or the statement will return no records. So let's say it finds "this" in `column2` and finds "that" in `column1`. Even though it found these values in those 2 columns this will still return no records because these values were not found in `column3` and `column 4`

**Using the OR operator**

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (column1 LIKE '%this%'
    OR column2 LIKE '%this%'
    OR column3 LIKE '%this%'
    OR column4 LIKE '%this%'
    OR column1 LIKE '%that%'
    OR column2 LIKE '%that%'
    OR column3 LIKE '%that%'
    OR column4 LIKE '%that%')
```

If I use the **OR** operator then it will return all the records that contain any of the values in any of the columns even though the record may only contain one of these values and not both.

What I am trying to accomplish with my statement is to only return the records that contain both "this" AND "that" in any of the columns even though other columns may not contain those values.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `AND` and `OR`.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (column1 LIKE '%this%'
    OR column2 LIKE '%this%'
    OR column3 LIKE '%this%'
    OR column4 LIKE '%this%')
AND (column1 LIKE '%that%'
    OR column2 LIKE '%that%'
    OR column3 LIKE '%that%'
    OR column4 LIKE '%that%')
```